# Force latex to put a figure and a table in the same page

Tags: floats, captions, minipage

I have tried both to use floating properties and static alignment to force latex to put a figure and a table next to each other with no success. Also, when I use `\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}` with the `\captionof` package, they will be put together, however, the mini-break causes the previous page to be cut in the middle. Anyone has a suggestion for me? Actually these figure and table must take the whole page.

```
%\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
%\centering
%\resizebox{13.4cm}{!}{\includegraphics{figures}}
%\captionof{figure}{figure i would like to be on top}
%\label{fig:BN_breakdown}
%%\end{figure}




%%\begin{table}[]
%\small
%\centering
%\captionof{table}{Table I would like to be bottom of the figure}
%\label{table}
%\centering
%\begin{tabular}{| l | l  | p{7cm}|c|}
%\hline 
%\textbf{}  & \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Time\%}  \\  
%\hline    
%\\ \hline
%\end{tabular}
%\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Have you tried loading the `afterpage` package and typing `\afterpage{\noindent \begin{minipage}...\end{minipage}}`?

Comment: So you want the figure+table combination to float together onto a single page and it should not disturb the textual flow?

Comment: yes. thats right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could load the [afterpage](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) package and encase the figure/table material in an `\afterpage{...}` statement: The typesetting of the argument of the `\afterpage` instruction is deferred until the start of the next page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{caption,afterpage,tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3] % filler text

\afterpage{% % defer placement until start of next page
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{figures} % choose width of graph
\captionof{figure}{Figure above table}
\label{fig:BN_breakdown}

\vspace{2cm} % choose the vertical separation between figure and table

\small
\captionof{table}{Table below figure}
\label{table}
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{| l | l | X | c |} % choose width of `tabularx`
\hline 
\textbf{} & \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Time \%}  \\  
\hline    
 & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\clearpage  % if needed/desired
}% end of argument of \afterpage

\lipsum[4-9] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice answer, however, it does violate the bottom border of the journal and interesting bundled another figure (the next page figure[t]) with these two. So all three on the same page now

Comment: @Amir - You should definitely adjust, as needed, the widths of the graph and `tabularx` env. (both currently `0.9\textwidth`) and the vertical separation generated by the `\vspace` instruction. Obviously, my answer doesn't incorporate any information (since it wasn't provided...) about things like "the bottom border of the journal".

Comment: I see your point, the problem is apparently `\clearpage` doesn't work here anywhere in this code statement

Comment: @Amir - I put the comment "if needed/desired" next to `\clearpage`, as I didn't know whether or not you would wish to allow running text to be placed below the `minipage` material. If the `minipage` takes up the full height of the text block anyway, you can certainly comment out (or simply delete) the `\clearpage` statement.

Comment: Your answer worked for me @Mico and thanks for that.  My concern was that this `\clearpage` is not working at all in any places inside `minipage`. That was all I was asking! I suspect these two are compatible at all.

Answer (score 10):

You can put the picture and the table into a single environment (e.g. `\begin{table}`) and use the `\captionof` command to add corresponding captions. Since you say the figure & table should occupy a single page, just add `[p]` specifier as an optional argument for the table.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{tikz} % for dummy picture

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] % dummy text

\begin{table}[p]
    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture} % dummy picture
        \fill circle (3cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \captionof{figure}{\protect\lipsum[2]} % dummy caption

    \hspace{\parskip}

    \captionof{table}{\protect\lipsum[2]} % dummy caption

    \begin{tabular}{| l | l | p{7cm} | c |} % dummy table
        \hline
        \textbf{} & \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Time\%} \\ \hline 
        \textbf{} & 00000 & 11111 & 22222 \\ 
        \textbf{} & 00000 & 11111 & 22222 \\ 
        \textbf{} & 00000 & 11111 & 22222 \\  \hline            
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-5] % dummy text

\end{document}
```

Comment: ooh 10 seconds faster than me, I'll delete my answer:-) +1